# Fisher Scientific T-30 Metal Detector - Circuit schematic

Tags: detector, metal

Looking for service manual for this old thing or a very similar detector it is from 1965 with germanium transistors .. I didn't think there was any real use for it until someone asked

.. some photos

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L5AW.jpg

board photos

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFvEP.jpg

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, but questions which seek off site resources, and questions on the repair of products which the asker cannot support with documentation and a clear understanding of the circuit are both outside the mission of this site.

Comment: Looks like a pretty obscure battery is called out.

Comment: I know what the circuit is .. it is either a multivibrator or a colpitts .. a schematic would make it so so much easier since many of the parts have drifted in value and are unmarked on the board .. or just a schematic from another detector from 1965

Comment: @Spehro .. yes it was a strange battery from back then .. I will probably change it to lithium ion and add an opamp to boost the output .. added photos of the board